# Why the return value of "echo" is always 1

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

After invoking the CMD "echo xxx" the %errorlevel% is always 1.
Even though "echo xxx" is executed successfully.

Comment: Was `%errorlevel%` already 1 before the `echo` ?

Comment: [ERRORLEVEL is not %ERRORLEVEL%](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/09/26/8965755.aspx).

Comment: yes, It seems that echo not effect %errorlevel%?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `echo something` has absolutely no effect on the error level and will not change errorlevel to 0 as that will just always succeed.

**For example:**

running a `echo something > c:\somefile.txt`, which will succeed actually creating the file, but not change errorlevel to 0.

```
c:\>copy nil c:
The system cannot find the file specified.

c:\>echo %errorlevel%
1

c:\>echo this.works > c:\test.txt

c:\>echo %errorlevel%
1

type c:\test.txt
this.works
```

Answer (score 3):

External commands like FINDSTR and XCOPY are actually separate programs (FINDSTR.EXE, XCOPY.EXE). External commands set the ERRORLEVEL upon both success and failure. By convention, 0 indicates success, and non-zero indicates an error. But some programs may not follow that convention.

ECHO is an internal command, meaning that the command is built into the CMD.EXE program itself. No additional program is needed. Internal commands behave differently.

If used on the command line, or within a batch script with a .BAT extension, then most internal commands set ERRORLEVEL upon failure, but do nothing to the ERRORLEVEL upon success. However, there are some exceptions. Both VER and VOL do set the ERRORLEVEL to 0 upon success.

When used within a batch script with a .CMD extension, all internal commands set the ERRORLEVEL upon both success and failure, just like external commands.

The ERRORLEVEL of 1 that you see after ECHO must have come from a prior command that failed. I've never seen ECHO fail. The only way I can imagine it could fail is if stdout is successfully redirected to a file, but the storage device cannot be written to for some reason such as if the device is full.

Comment: Not sure about other versions (now i only can test on XP), but inside a .bat file `vol` or `ver` commands reset the errorlevel. And the same inside a .cmd

Answer (score 2):

`echo` is a curious command. Let's see how it behaves

**When `echo` command works**

If errorlevel is 0 before `echo`, after `echo`, `errorlevel` will be 0 (the obvious case)

If errorlevel is 1 before `echo`, after `echo`, `errorlevel` will be 1. Echo does not change errorlevel

**When `echo` command "fails"**

Can echo fail? Let's create a case where it "fails". Open two command windows on the same directory. In first one run `pause > file.txt` to generate a file and place a lock on it while the pause command is waiting a keypress. In second command window run `echo something > file.txt`. In this case, the `echo` command will fail, as the first command window hold a lock on the file, so the second one is not able to write to the file. Properly talking the *echo has not failed*, but the redirection does, but just to see what happens

If `errorlevel` is 1 before running `echo`, it is still 1 after the `echo` (the obvious case)

If `errolevel` is 0 before running `echo`, it is still 0 after the `echo`

So, it seems that the echo command behaves identically in the two cases

**BUT** if we change the way `echo` is executed to

```
echo something && echo works || echo fails
```

then the behaviour changes a bit

**When `echo` command works**

No difference. `errorlevel` will not change, keeping the value it had before running the `echo` command.

**When `echo` command "fails"**

Using the `echo something > file && echo works || echo fails` then, if `errorlevel` is 1 before running `echo`, it keeps its value.

But if `errorlevel` is 0 and the `echo` command fails, in this case, with this construct of the command, `errorlevel` will show the failure and change its value to 1

[image: capture of test on errorlevel]

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. However, If errorlevel is 0, When I try the command "echo something > file && echo works || echo fails", even if "echo something > file" is failed, the errorlevel keeps 0, not 1.

Comment: Actually, the redirection fails if the file is locked, not the ECHO command. Redirection occurs before any command is executed. If the redirection fails, then the command(s) is never executed. The concept is more obvious if you redirect a parenthesized block to a locked file, and put multiple commands within the parentheses.

Comment: @dbenham: Thank you, yes, that is the reason for the quotes on the "fails". But i've changed the comment about the redirection failure not the echo failure.

Comment: @iceKing: I`ve included a capture of my screen on test of errorlevel. For me the errorlevel changes. Are you testing the `%errorlevel%` variable value of directly using the `if errorlevel` construct?